# Dates 'Text to Columns' function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm automating some data importing from several sensors but one of them is causing some issues with its dates.

It delivers timestamps as `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss`, when my local standard is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`, and this seems to be causing some issues.

First, I tried solving this by replacing all the `"-"` with `"/"`. This works when done manually, but I can't get it to work in VBA.

So, then I tried to do it with the `Text to Columns` function, but again I can't get VBA to return the same result as doing it manually. Recording a macro resulted in the code below, but it doesn't seem to specify that the column consists of dates.

Relevant code:

```
        Range("AE10").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AE10"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Full macro:

```
Sub ImportBV()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'locate data file
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, path As String, decsep As String, thosep As String


path = ActiveWorkbook.path
directory = path & "\data\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.csv")
decsep = Sheets("Backend").Cells(7, 3).Value
thosep = Sheets("Backend").Cells(7, 4).Value

If fileName = "" Then
    MsgBox ("No .csv file found in " & directory)
    Exit Sub
End If

'import sheet
Name (directory & fileName) As (directory & "BlueVis_Export.txt") 'the csv format causes issues for English/international regional settings users
fileName = Dir(directory & "BlueVis_Export.txt")
Workbooks.OpenText (directory & fileName), DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True, DecimalSeparator:=decsep, ThousandsSeparator:=thosep

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(1).Range("AB10").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AB10"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(1).Range("AE10").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AE10"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Workbooks(fileName).Save
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Workbooks.Open (path & "\Timestep.xlsm")

Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(1).Copy _
    After:=Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Worksheets("README")


Workbooks(fileName).Close

Name (directory & fileName) As (directory & "BlueVis_Export.csv") 'Return to csv format for possible reuse


'Increase dt

Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Activate

Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Sheets(4).Range(Cells(10, 28), Cells(10, 29)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range("A1")

Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Sheets(4).Cells(10, 32).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range("C1")
Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Sheets(4).Delete

Application.Run "'Timestep.xlsm'!change_dt"



Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Save

'move data to import paste
    ' Row = beginrij van Timestep converter row2 = beginrij van import sheet
row = 7
row2 = 5

Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Copy _
After:=Workbooks("data importer.xlsm").Worksheets("backend")

Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Activate
Application.Run "'Timestep.xlsm'!ClearData"
Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Save
Workbooks("Timestep.xlsm").Close

Sheets(20).Select

Do While Sheets(20).Cells(row, 2) <> ""
    Sheets("I BV").Cells(row2, 6).Value = Sheets(20).Cells(row, 2).Value
    Sheets("I BV").Cells(row2, 7).Value = Sheets(20).Cells(row, 3).Value
    Sheets("I BV").Cells(row2, 8).Value = Sheets(20).Cells(row, 4).Value
    row = row + 1
    row2 = row2 + 1
Loop
If Sheets("import interface").Cells(18, 7).Value <> "Rotated" Then
    Dim r As Integer
    r = Sheets("Import interface").Cells(18, 7).Value
    row2 = 5
    Do While Sheets("I BV").Cells(row2, 6).Value <> ""
        Sheets("I BV").Cells(row2, 9).Value = r
        row2 = row2 + 1
    Loop
    'Sheets("I BV").Range(Cells(4, 9), Cells(row2, 9)).Value = Sheets("import interface").Cells(18, 7).Value
End If


'return to normal
Sheets(20).Delete
Sheets("import interface").Select
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

If Sheets("import interface").Cells(18, 7).Value <> "Rotated" Then
    MsgBox ("Import succesful.")
Else
    MsgBox ("Import succesful. Remember to fill in the 'reactor' column in the 'I BV' sheet manually.")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually it is specifying that they're dates. The [`Range.TextToColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) docs note that the `FieldInfo` specifies the column data type. `4` is DMY Date format - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype).

Comment: Have you tried changing the [date format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8E10019E-D5D8-47A1-BA95-DB95123D273E) of the cells to the one you want?

Comment: **some issues** is not a particularly helpful description. Can you be specific about what is happening? Hard to reproduce your problem with so little information.

Comment: The issue is that Excel treats my dates as a string rather than a date, even after running the above code. This is an issue for me because my data importing script also does some math with the dates (to standardize the time between measurements to 15min rather than 10 seconds)

Comment: I could send you a raw data file if it helps @RonRosenfeld

Comment: @BartPostma Why don't you just format your timestamp then ?

Comment: *Dates as a string* is a common problem that is usually best handled at the level of importing the data (before the data actually gets to the worksheet). So, yes, a sample of the raw data file that is causing the problem, and the coding for your import method, would be where I would start. You can post a file to some public sharing site (eg dropbox, OneDrive, etc), and post a link here.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You can find the raw data file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ps1lnwgwd2op392/BlueVis_Export_beginning_from_16-9-2019_13_29_28.csv?dl=0  
And I'll put the full import macro in my post. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your data and code, and this seems quite complicated, in part because you have multiple column headers.

You absolutely MUST convert to proper dates before importing to Excel, otherwise you will have a mixed bag of importing depending on whether the "day" is >12 or not.

My suggestion would be to use Power Query for the import.

- Select the source (From Text/CSV)
- Since you have ten rows of headers, you won't be able to just format the date columns so:

  - Transpose the table
  - Merge the header rows, using semicolon as a delimiter
  - transpose again.
  - Promote the first row to the header
  - Now select the date columns

    - Right click on the column
    - Select Change Type with Locale

      - I used English(Europe)
  - Transpose the table again
  - Split the first column by the semicolon
  - Transpose a third time to get back to the normal configuration
  - Close and load

You may need to format the date columns back into date/time, as they may show up as  decimal numbers eg: 43724.6587

**EDIT**
Given that you may not be able to use Power Query, here is a "pure VBA" method that should properly convert the dates in `d-m-y hh:mm:ss` format to proper dates.

It depends on importing the column as `TEXT` so that Excel won't do any funny things on it, and then accomplishing the conversion.

Selecting the date columns is the only potentially tricky part, but if they are in the same column each run, you may only need to test for their presence (the sample file had some blank date/time columns).

You may need to edit some of the arguments for the `Connection`, especially if they can be variable. Ask if you have issues.

```
Sub importSensor()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;D:\Users\Ron\Desktop\BlueVis_Export_beginning_from_16-9-2019_13_29_28.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "BlueVis_Export_beginning_from_16-9-2019_13_29_28"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        )
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
        .TextFileThousandsSeparator = " "
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

Dim WS As Worksheet, WB As Workbook
Dim arrDtCols()
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS = WB.ActiveSheet
Dim R As Range, V As Variant
Dim vDtParts, vTimePart
Dim I As Long, J As Long

'Many ways of defining the date cols
' and you may need to add some checks that there are dates in the columns
arrDtCols = Array(28, 31, 34, 40, 49)
For I = LBound(arrDtCols) To UBound(arrDtCols)
    With WS
        Set R = Range(.Cells(10, arrDtCols(I)), .Cells(.Rows.Count, arrDtCols(I)).End(xlUp))
        V = R
            For J = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
                vDtParts = Split(Split(V(J, 1), " ")(0), "-")
                vTimePart = Split(V(J, 1), " ")(1)
                V(J, 1) = DateSerial(vDtParts(2), vDtParts(1), vDtParts(0)) + CDate(vTimePart)
            Next J
        R = V
'could set format for the column here, as desired.

    End With
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It looks like it would work but sadly I can't use anything with dependencies that need to be installed because all our clients (who are not very tech-savy to put it lightly) need to use the data importer. I'll try to convince the manufacturer of the sensor to fix this instead.

Comment: @bartpostma power query is available in Excel 2010 plus and is part of Excel 2016. Unfortunately in the earlier versions of Excel 2010 - 2013 it has to be installed as an ad in

Comment: @bartpostma VBA solution will be forthcoming later this evening

Comment: @BartPostma "Pure" VBA solution posted